# Anthropomorphism in Esperanto

Tags: word-usage

In English, sometimes we says things like:

- The company wants me to work more.
- Microsoft is angry at Apple.
- I called the company.

Can we say the same thing in Esperanto? Does it still make sense?

- La firmao volas, ke mi laboru pli ofte.
- Microsoft estas kolera pri Apple.
- Mi telefonis al la firmao.

Answer (score 7):

It's a rhetorical figure (metonymy), which is not related to any particular language, so I see no reason why it should not work in Esperanto.

See the [Wikipedia Entry on Metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy); the relationship would be 'containment', where "Microsoft" stands in for the board/CEO/... of the company itself.